# SagePay: list of transactions

Tags: php, api, integration, payment, opayo

I'm just wondering if it's available to fetch list of all payments from SagePay. I'm currently able to get transaction details by providing transaction_id and send request to https://sagepay.com/api/v1/transactions/{$transaction_id}. I'm currently getting all payments by CSV export from SagePay dashboard, but I would like to automate it. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: You should check the documentation provided by them. If you don't have one, contact them and ask for.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Of course I did check documentation, but couldn't find what I need and that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'old' API to achieve this - just issue a getTransactionList command.

Documentation at: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1186/download-document/reportingandapiprotocol102v0.5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, just give the required fields in the xml form and  send request to respective url.

```
    $crypt = MD5($string . '<password>' . $password . '</password>');
    $xml = 'XML=<vspaccess>'.$string.'<signature>'.$crypt.'</signature>
            </vspaccess>';
```

where $string is the whole xml before the password.
It will also help you making the signature field in xml syntax.

Read [this pdf](https://www.opayo.co.uk/file/1186/download-document/reportingandapiprotocol102v0.5.pdf) (page 85 for you) :-)

Comment: Does not work anymore.